# Programatically change the contents of a WPF Datagrid Cell

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid (.NET framework 4) that gets its ItemsSource from an array of myObject. One of the columns/variables of myObject is a DateTime. Is there a way to change the drawing event of the DataGrid row so that I can display something else in the cells of that column other than each object's DateTime?

Comment: The drawing event is not the right time to change data.

Comment: I don't want to change the data of myObject. I want to change what is displayed.

Comment: Still not the proper use of the drawing event.

Answer (score 0):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns` to False, and define your columns manually using `DataGridTextColumn`, DataGridTemplateColumn`, etc.

---

**Edit** using the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event, you can modify the column's output by adding an `IValueConverter`:

```
    void MyGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        // check if the current column is the target
        if (e.PropertyName == "MyDateproperty")
        {
            // assuming it's a Text-type column
            var column = (e.Column as DataGridTextColumn);
            if (column != null)
            {
                var binding = column.Binding as Binding;
                if (binding != null)
                {
                    // add a converter to the binding
                    binding.Converter = new StringFormatConverter();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now, define `StringFormatConverter` in the usual way, converting the Date/Time value to whatever:

```
public class StringFormatConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var col = (DateTime?)value;
        return (col == null) ? null : col.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have a callback for the autogeneratecolumn event in order to change the header of the columns and I am not going to get rid of it. I want the datagrid to display something else in the cell besides the datetime value, so when I add a row, instead of the value in the column being 01/01/0001, I want it to be a string that says "Immediatley" or whatnot based on the time thatwould have been displayed there

Comment: Why do refuse to get get rid of AutoGenerateColumns?  Rather than modify just set it explicitly.

Comment: What if I want it to display a button on some rows, and text on other rows in the same column?

Comment: @user1241727 then I think you should use an `IValueConverter`.  See my updated answer...

Comment: @user1241727 you might want to regroup and figure out which question you're asking ... adding a button is different than just converting the text.